# PHP - store query results in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from my table and save all the results in an array.

```
$query = " SELECT id,sent_to FROM `table` WHERE `ac` = 0 AND `cut` < CURRENT_DATE() ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$sentToList = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $sentToList = $row['sent_to']; }
print_r($sentToList); // to check if the results have been saved in the variable

$sent_to = explode(',', $sentToList); //for my next step
```

When I'm printing `$sentToList` I'm getting only the last result of the query. There are similar questions answered but I didn't quite get the explanation. Thank you.

Comment: This will be even cleaner and simpler `while($row[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  }`

Comment: @MilanChheda I don't understand why, but I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for mentioning it =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$sentToList = $row['sent_to'];` this will save value of `$row['sent_to'];` in variable. So this will update `$sentToList` every time

Try this

```
$sentToList[] = $row['sent_to'];
```

this will assign value into array

Comment: So my code created a new variable that is not an array called `$sentToList` instead of using the array variable create on the line before?
it worked by the way haha.